# Why rdp local drives don't work until I view the settings and reconnect?

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop

I have some users that use remote desktop connection and recently they cannot access their local network drives within the remote session.

When I view the settings under local resources and click on more settings, the relevant network drive is checked. And as soon as I reconnect the rdp, the local network drive works until they restart their pc.

Is there any reason why this happens, and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

after opening **remote desktop connection** client, before connection change the settings you require in **Local Resources** tab or in any other, then go back to **General** tab and click **Save** button. This will save Remote Desktop Client settings for all connections. If you like different settings for different locations/remote desktops - use **Save As...** button and in that way save your connection settings in separate files wherever you prefer.

Good Luck!

Comment: I will save and see if it changes anything, but I don't actually change the settings; I just look at it for it to work again.